# How do I pass the date value from the js controller to the apex method?

Tags: apex, soql, aura, date, js

Trying to pass the date value I get an error. How to fix it?

**//cmp**

```
...
<aura:attribute name="dateExchangeRates" type="Date"/>
...
```

**//js**

```
getDataForTheDate : function(component, helper){
        let dateExchangeRates = component.get("v.dateExchangeRates");
        if(dateExchangeRates != ''){
            let action = component.get('c.getListExchangeRatesForTheDate');
                action.setParams({"dateExchangeRates" : dateExchangeRates});
                action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                    let state = response.getState();
                    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                        //here is my code
                    }
                });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }
```

**//apxc**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getListExchangeRatesForTheDate (Date dateExchangeRates){
        String currencys = converter(getListFieldsCurrenciesForRequest());
        return Database.query('SELECT Date__c, Base_Currency__c, ' + currencys + ' FROM Exchange_Rate__c WHERE Date__c = :' + dateExchangeRates);
```

**//error**

```
FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: '2021-05-30'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a query exception and has nothing to do with way you are passing in the attributes.

Try using the below

```
return Database.query('SELECT Date__c, Base_Currency__c, ' + currencys + ' FROM Exchange_Rate__c WHERE Date__c = :dateExchangeRates');
```

Note apex variables are automatically resolved for you